# Quantum History. What mechanisms are there for a newly discovered past to effect the more general past?

Tags: history, quantum, simulated-worlds

Let's say we start the simulation on Earth in 1900. And we use classical physics unless the participants start looking at tiny objects. This allows us to reduce the amount of memory needed to run the simulation. So physics is a compression algorithm.

All good so far.

But how much **human** history do we need to create for a consistent world. Perhaps 150 years of high fidelity history dwindling away in fidelity to 10,000 years.

In this simulation the archaeology is also like a quantum observation and  the missing bits of history only become certain as they are unearthed.

In this world if you look for bad histories you will more likely find bad histories and if you look for good ones you will more likely find good ones.  And a story might be written where competing interests search for histories that favour their current presents and futures.

There may be dark forces trying to unearth sinister historical conspiracies that they can manipulate to reinforce their power, and good forces trying to find golden ages and righteous societies and groups that shine a light on the present and future.

A simple example of this would be finding a treasure chest on an Island then opening it to find gold or keepsakes. This would effect the present.

Are there mechanisms that would allow the newly discovered past to effect the past more generally than just the specific past unearthed, or just on the current understanding and influence of recorded history?

eg. someone discovers ancient texts referring Yetis, and so increases the probability that yeti's will be discovered in a very remote part of the Himalayas.

Comment: I am not sure this is about worldbuilding or better suited for writing

Comment: @user535733 i cant speak for op but i think its like this: person a is looking for some peaceful village with "open gates" (that doesnt exist) and person b is looking for a warring superpower filled with giant walls (that also doesnt exist) if they both decide to look in point X then if person a gets there first they will find the peaceful village's remains, and if person b looks first they will find the warring city.

Comment: Yes @Topcode that the first person to look defines the broad outline. But further looking may add a bit of a slant to the initial discovery.

Comment: (1) Look up [confirmation bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). (2) This is exactly how real history works. We know the history of the 2011 American baseball season very very much better than the history of the [Egyptian-Hittite war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian–Hittite_peace_treaty) in the 1270s BCE. (3) And that was a very important war. The point being that our knowledge of history becomes less and less detailed as we go deeper into time, and becomes completely nebulous around 4000 years before present, where *history* becomes *prehistory*.

Comment: So...if history is important, then I want to want to discover lots of ancient history so it goes my preferred way? But how does that affect the present? If I'm the first to happily discover that Major League Baseball in 1955 headed a vast evil conspiracy to enslave South Dakota...but South Dakota isn't enslaved today, then history didn't go my way after all. Or does the world blur and suddenly South Dakota has been enslaved since 1955 because of my discovery?

Comment: @user535733 say I discover a people who believe in ancient aliens then the probability of Humans being the Galactic firstborn drops.  If Dr Jones discovers images of flying chariots the chance of a breakaway civilisation goes up.  I may find documents in an archive from the 1800s that pertains to an existing family that hints of esoteric lost knowledge they possess. Though some of this may depend on having bots with undetermined history, I'm not sure.  Inheritance documents may change reality, I am interested in other discovery types with impact on the future.

Comment: @user535733 ancient philosophies may influence currnet ones.  New mathematics and botany might too perhaps?

Comment: How does the influence manifest? Does the world blur and everybody's memories change and suddenly some of my children never existed? Or is more academic: Now we know that Cthulthu monsters are real and we are doomed, but it's still lovely outside so let's have a picnic? That seems the crux of the is-this-a-trope question. One way is a variation on time-travel paradoxes. The other is ordinary melancholy drama (or perhaps farce).

Comment: @user535733 no blurring. This isn't about recorded history. It is actual history.  There is no bllurring or change. It is just like schrodingers cat but for the past that hasn't already written into the initial settings of the simulation. Its like finding a treasure chest. The contents only determine themselves when you open the box. Some of this only impacts the present like the treasure chest, but there may be other subtler effects that would be interesting to explore.

Comment: Are you saying that folks in the simulated present will be strongly influenced by whatever gets discovered in the random past? "*Hey, turns out Phoenicians were goat-headed demigods who wanted us to become cannibals. I don't know when we lapsed on our cannibalism, but I suppose we should resume. Stand still.*" The only trope there is gullible people.

Comment: There is a sad joke that Russia is a country with the oblivious past. There were just too many mood swings and re-evaluations of some historic events that it is not quite clear which of those were good and defining for the country. So, have some err... ruling system, e.g., a monarchy, then a revolution, than 70 years of another ruling system with some Robespierre stuff in the middle, then have a counter-revolution to a yet another ruling system, resembling the first, but not quite, keep that for another 30 years. Now you have big discussions on the role of pretty much every historical figure.

Comment: @AlexP that is also a function writing, we know a lot more about civilizations that kept written records than younger ones without writing.

Comment: @user535733 "Major League Baseball in 1955 headed a vast evil conspiracy to enslave South Dakota...but South Dakota isn't enslaved" yes but now nobody will trust the mlb which is part of your narrative

Answer (score 2):

> /There may be dark forces trying to unearth sinister historical
> conspiracies that they can manipulate to reinforce their power, and
> good forces trying to find golden ages and righteous societies and
> groups that shine a light on the present and future.
>
> Has this trope any literary precedent?/

**Yes.**  It happens plenty in the real world.  As regards literary precedent, George Orwell's 1984 is a fine example.

https://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/n/1984/critical-essays/the-mutability-of-history

> One of the issues raised in 1984 is the idea that history is mutable
> or changeable, that truth is what the Party deems it to be, and that
> the truths found in history are the bases of the principles of the
> future. Some Fascist German leaders of the time boasted that if you
> tell a lie loud enough and often enough, people will accept it as
> truth. The Stalinists perfected this modus operandi by re-writing
> people and events in and out of history or distorting historical facts
> to suit the Party's purposes. "Who controls the past controls the
> future: who controls the present controls the past," runs the Party
> slogan in 1984

What timely words!  In any case you do not need to be in a simulation to have persons attempt to manipulate history for their own ends, nefarious or enlightened.

.

Answer (score 2):

### Akashic Record Vs. 'There is no Real Time'

So I once heard a theoretical physicist say that time might be a fluctuating wave function, and that we're all time travelers. Going forward or backwards in time appears identical, as it is only change. There IS no past, and it is only our perception of change we experience. So in this model, you have no problem. There is nothing to find. Every physical piece of evidence is a material item from the starting conditions that either is or isn't there. There IS no before.

I don't think that's what you want. The Akashic record is a proposed structure by spiritualists, a giant file containing the previous states of everything in the entire universe. It is literally a store of the past. Only in your model, the books there are largely blank until you look at them.

The problem is that I think you want the physical evidence of ancient things to materialize out of no where as people find them. This implies that much of the CURRENT reality is a low resolution approximated reality, waiting to fill in. People are everywhere, and have traveled everywhere, so they would have already observed almost everything. To get what you want, people would need to dig deep and travel to abandoned and inhospitable parts of the world where human observation has never gone.

It also means that what people want is what they find. Archaeology is usually about surprises. People don't know what they'll find, but often try to make the evidence match their preconceptions. Funny how new discoveries seem to invalidate the old ones.

You may have people who can actually CHANGE history, not merely create it. Any property of a piece of matter can be questioned. Look up [Piltdown Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piltdown_Man#:%7E:text=The%20Piltdown%20Man%20was%20a,a%20previously%20unknown%20early%20human.).  Archaeologists believed they had proof of one path of ancient history. It was unquestionable - until it wasn't. Perhaps the constant search for new reality is even able to alter the existing record. Carbon dating proved the fossil was 100 million years old? Oh, wait, it was exposed to a fire, that's wrong. This bone is clearly one species - oh, wait, now it was all a misinterpretation. So even 'Fixed' history is malleable.

But I doubt you'll get much actual malevolent benefit. Even Nazis seeking proof of an ancient Aryan master world of Thule would need to convince people it was relevant. Popular opinion might invalidate the reality of what they found. An ancient Aryan bell space ship might become the visiting ship of a great black African empire with the right spin and a change in science.

Or maybe the past IS real for these folks, a place you could travel to. If so, like opening a portal to an area in a game that hasn't been created, there would be buffering problems until reality shifted in. But most of reality requires too many individual details for the observer to make them on their own. A master creator/computer would need to intervene to handle the details. Malevolence could enter in if there is more than ONE master computer, and their opportunity to alter fixed reality is only there at the moment of observation. So you could have devils or angels (so to speak) trying to make their plug and using mankind as their proxies.